# Put arrays in one variable for ruby slim

Tags: ruby, arrays, templates, slim-lang

I have [Slim](http://slim-lang.com) template

```
# main.slim
- for item in items do
  td = item.a
  td = item.b
```

I have Ruby code

```
# main.rb
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
```

I want render HTML from this template.

I want show in result:

```
# main.html
<td>1</td><td>4</td>
<td>2</td><td>5</td>
<td>3</td><td>6</td>
```

How I can put "a" and "b" arrays in "items" variable (or object)?

I render from Ruby:

```
Slim::Template.new("main.slim").render(nil, :items => items)
```

Comment: Don't use `for` in Ruby, it's a bit of an antipattern as it actually just calls `each`. You should do `items.each do |item|`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Agreed for Ruby code. In templates I've always considered it OK. It's consistent with many other templating languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/Array.html#method-i-zip) will pack up n arrays of length m into an array of m tuples where each tuple has n-elements. Tuples are just arrays as opposed to objects w/ named fields. That said, this could make it easier to iterate over.

```
items = a.zip(b)
for item in items do
  td = item[0]
  td = item[1]
end
```

Comment: Might be better to `flatten` that array and treat them as individual items instead of pairs.